# nuxt.js : is there a way on a page refresh to prevent the request to the server

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

By default, nuxt.js makes a request to a server when user makes a page refresh. I would like, in some cases, prevent this request to the server, because the page rendered by the server will be useless and will have to be reconstructed by the client.

Is it possible ? I didn't find how to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58465065/how-do-i-change-the-url-of-the-page-in-nuxt-ssr-mode-without-reloading-the-whole

Comment: not clear what you want exactly. If u mean when user hit refresh browser button to not server render than its not possible

Comment: That's what I meant. Thank you.