# I don't want to rerender the page when changing the dynamic params on Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, url-parameters

I have a simple page with two dynamic params when I'm on the page and changing the URL params fetch method will run again. I don't want this behavior.

fetch method:

```
async fetch() {
    await this.getFlightResult();
}
```

getResult Method:

```
async getResult() {

    this.$router.push({
        path: `/air/${originCity?.id}-${destinationCity?.id}/${originCity?.name}-${destinationCity?.name}`,
    });
    await this.getFlightResult();
}
```

getResultMethod:

```
async getFlightResult(){
   const { data } = await this.$axios.get(`/api/v1/flights')
}
```

I have this code when changing the URL params run fetch method and getResult method together and it causes this happen.

Comment: Hi, please show us some code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the URL of the page in Nuxt SSR mode without reloading the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58465065/how-do-i-change-the-url-of-the-page-in-nuxt-ssr-mode-without-reloading-the-whole)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the query parameters without changing the path parameter and so, not re-rendering the page:

```js
this.$router.push({query: { myFirstQuery: 'foo', mySecondQuery: 'bar'}})
```

You can then watch the queries with for example :

```js
watch: {
    '$route.query': {
      immediate: true,
      handler(newVal){
        // updating your values here
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't want to render the page again after changing the URL, but in this solution, the page will be rendered again

Comment: Yep you're right, updating params re-mount the page but using query it doesn't !